# Bind to onclick event in MarkupString without JS interop

Tags: c#, svg, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm currently writing a Blazor site that retrieves some generic SVG from a web API. This SVG's elements all have ID's. I would like to capture the onclick events on these ID's. I'm fairly sure it's possible with JS interop. But I'm hoping there's a nicer purely Blazor or SVG way of doing this. Is there one?

The ID's basically look like this:

```
chart1-x1-y1
```

Comment: Dont think any blazor specific way is possible just yet.

Comment: SVG is Xml format so you can modify the XML with any XML class in Net.

Comment: @jdweng That is an option. But I'm looking/hoping for a solution that won't require going trough the SVG a second time. It would lessen the benefits of rendering the SVG in a rest API

Comment: You said "SVG way of doing this".

Comment: @jdweng I'll clarify that. I mean is there something I can add to the SVG on the Rest API that I can use in my client

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API.